# how to generate api.ai url of my agent in dialoglow(api.ai) and use that api URL in PHP to store user's inputs in MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, json, dialogflow-es

In api.i(dialogflow), I want to take user's inputs like name, age, mail etc and store them in my MYSQL Database using PHP.

How to generate the public API URL of my agent in dialogflow? I have tried enabling the webhook to handle fulfillment but I stuck at generating an URL.
After generating that URL, How it can be used in PHP to get JSON Data so that I can store the values of user inputs in MYSQL Database.

- Sample Bot: Hi, Tell me your name?
- User: John
- Sample Bot: Okay, tell me your email?
- User: john678jersy@gmail.com.

---

In this way, I want to read data from a user and store them in MYSQL Database USING PHP. I am comfortable with PHP.

I was searching at many places but couldn't find the right process. 
Any help would be **appreciable.**

**Thanks in Advance!**

Comment: What do you mean by _How to generate the public API URL of my agent in dialogflow_? I can help you with saving everything to databse, I myself have done that, but what's this public API URL you're talking anout?

Comment: Hi @JacobCelestine thank you for responding,  I was saying about the URL which should be placed on the fulfillment tab of Dialogflow(api.ai). I wrote PHP code and deployed it in Heroku and then generated an URL. I placed that URL in fulfillment, enabled all webhooks when I am trying to test my agent through webhook demo integration, it was sending "Error 500:internal server error" and I even don't know that I am receiving the JSON data or not from my agent to PHP file. I want to read JSON data and store user inputs using PHP into MYSQL Database.

Comment: Your code could be wrong, can you please post that as well? Also, maybe you should try writing your errors to a file in the php file so that you can see what the problem is. Also see to it that your file have all the permissions needed, and if there's an error log, please post that as well.

Comment: @JacobCelestine Can you please give me your linkedin id or facebook so that I can share my php file and talk to you on this?

Comment: Here's my LinkedIn: https://www.linkedin.com/in/jacobceles/

Comment: Hi @JacobCelestine, I am unable to send request to you as it is in Inmail, so here is my LinkedIn please send me a Connect request  (https://www.linkedin.com/in/iamphanisairam/)

Comment: I didn't receive any request

Comment: @JacobCelestine, your linkedin is in "Inmail" credits so take mine and send to me so that we can have a talk this is my linkedin (https://www.linkedin.com/in/iamphanisairam/)

Comment: Same for me. Contact me on fb: facebook.com/jacobceles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking your php file is wrong. Here's a sample php file so you can refer it and fix your code:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
ob_start();
$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$json = json_decode($requestBody, true);

$text = $json['result']['resolvedQuery'];
$response = json_encode(array(
            "source" => "webhook",
            "speech" => $text,
            "displayText" => $text,
            "contextOut" => array()
        ));

ob_end_clean();
echo $response;
?>
```